# Handler postDelayed doesn't post on delayed?

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I want to change some values onBackPressed method... And i override it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

            final Handler backHandler = new Handler();
            backHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    exitCount = 0;
                    Log.d("exitCount", "exitCount: " + exitCount);
                }
            }, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

}
```

But the problem is handler posts immediately... There's no delay. Where am i doing wrong?
Sorry if this is a lame question, i'm pretty new on Android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` value is zero. Try declaring your constant with a delay value you choose. see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT)

Comment: But i need it to delay exactly Toast.LENGTH_SHORT do you know how millis that is?

Comment: Found it by trying some :) 2000 millis work just fine :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: 2seconds I think. But it could change with the android implemetation

Answer (score 1):

Make the handler part of an activity (or part of a thread you are posting a message to if its not for the UI thread), and use a millisecond delay rather than Toast.LENGTH_SHORT which has a value of zero so it will happen instantly.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("tag", "Hello, Handler!");
            }
        }, 1000); // one second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use belo code I hope it will work.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                backHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    exitCount = 0;
                    Log.d("exitCount", "exitCount: " + exitCount);
                }
            }, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
```